# Is it possible to get more reviews permission

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I have already reviews for all categories and now I have no limits.

[image]

I have seen that some users has privileges for reviewing more than 20.

I know that I can review more next day.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is it possible to me to review more than limit?
2. How other users can review more than limit?
3. What should I do to review more?
4. Is it possible to give the rights to any specific user for review as much as user want?

Comment: People have absolutely no obligation to give reasons why they downvoted. Perhaps it is because they don't understand why you want to be able to review more. GIven that you've reached your limit on every single queue, that would mean you've done 160 reviews today, which is significantly more than others. They might also disagree with [some](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7026316) of your reviews.

Comment: I downvoted because there is a world outside your window, and the review system is limited so _you can explore it_.

Comment: What are you talking about @KevinBrown? There is nothing outside that is more important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rate limits on reviews are needed to distribute review tasks and to ensure that overactive reviewers don't dominate the reviews. When those reviewers [make](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6882411) [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5097206) [judgments](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4902623) in [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4863595), it could lead to spam, vandalism, and other bad things making it onto the site. By capping the number of reviews per day per person, it gives other people a chance to review items, yielding a more diverse review base and limiting the harm from one bad reviewer.

Also, Stack Overflow tends to rate limit many other moderation-related tasks to (as Kevin puts it) encourage you to enjoy the outside world.

In general, the only users able to exceed these limits are moderators, because if we can't be trusted in review the site has much larger problems than this.